# How do I select count and minus sub count in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, count, group-by

Below is my database table.

```
id     name    status     user_id
1      A       1          1
2      B       2          1 
3      C       2          1
4      D       2          1
5      E       3          1

6      F       2          2
7      G       2          2
8      H       1          2
```

I would like to count all record where `user_id` = 1 and minus sub count records where `user_id` = 1 AND `status` = 2. The result should be as following.

```
 count_all    count_status_2   count_left      user_id 
 5            3                2               1
```

Below is my sql query.

```
SELECT a.count_all, b.count_status_2, (a.count_all - b.count_all_bought) AS count_left, a.user_id  
FROM
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, user_id FROM table WHERE user_id = 1
) a 
CROSS JOIN 
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_status_2 FROM table WHERE user_id = 1 AND status = 2
) b
```

But I am not sure if it is an efficient solution. Are there any better solutions?

Further, I would like to get the following result group by `user_id`.

```
count_all    count_status_2   count_left      user_id 
 5            3                2               1
 3            2                1               2
```

How should I write the sql query to get the second result? Sorry if I ask for two solutions in one question, because it is similar, just add group by `user_id`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can instead use *conditional aggregation*:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, 
       SUM(status=2) AS count_status_2,
       COUNT(*)- SUM(status=2) AS count_left,
       user_id 
FROM table 
WHERE user_id = 1
-- Add GROUP BY and remove above WHERE for ALL users
GROUP BY user_id
```

Comment: Thanks for your great sql. Why cannot I use alias count_all - count_status_2? Or MySQL does not work that way?

Comment: @OConnor  You can't reuse an alias in the `SELECT` clause.